# Jquery how to set a select option text back to default after changing option on another select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 select dropdowns and when I select option 4 on the first select dropdown then it changes the text of the other select dropdowns. But if I decide I actually want the first option, and I go back to selecting it I want to have the other options changed back to the default text before I selected option 4 on the first select dropdown, I cannot get it to work - I tried `change()`, `clone()`, setting it back to `val(0)` etc.

Another issue I have is that when I select option 4 the dropdown text changes as it should, but the values (dinner_costs and breakfast_costs) are displaying 0 until I select the option, which then displays the value.

```js
$('body').on('change', '.select-update', function(e){

$('.room-table').each(function(){
 var persons_price = $(this).data('price-p-person');
 var ss = $(this).data('ss');

 var num_persons = Number($(this).find('.num-person').val());

 if(num_persons >= 1) {
  var dinner = Number($(this).find('.num-dinner').val());
  var breakfast = Number($(this).find('.num-bf').val());
  var room_cost = persons_price * num_persons;

  var dinner_costs = num_persons * dinner;
  var breakfast_costs = num_persons * breakfast;


  if(num_persons == 1){
   room_cost = room_cost + ss;

  }
  else if(num_persons == 4){
   room_cost = persons_price * 2;
   room_cost = persons_price * 2;

   dinner_costs = dinner * 2;

   $(this).find(".num-dinner .option-two-course-dinn").text('Adult 2 course dinner ' + dinner_costs + ' pp Child under 5 Free');
   $(this).find('.num-dinner .option-three-course-dinn').text('Adult 3 course dinner ' + dinner_costs + ' pp Child under 5 Free');

   breakfast_costs = breakfast * 2;

   $(this).find(".num-bf .option-basic-bf").text('Adult basic breakfast ' + breakfast_costs + ' pp Child under 5 Free');
   $(this).find('.num-dinner .option-full-bf').text('Adult full breakfast ' + breakfast_costs + ' pp Child under 5 Free');
  }

  var total = room_cost + dinner_costs;

 }
 else total = 0;
 $(this).find('.total').val(total);
 total = 0;
 $('.total').each(function(){
  val = $(this).val() | 0;
  total = val ? (parseFloat(total + val)) : total;
 });
 var num_days = $('.date-picks').find("#days").val();
 $('.grandtotal').val(total * num_days);
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="booking-form needs-validation" name="book-room-form" action="" id="contactForm" method="post" novalidate>

<h1>Star Wars Room</h1>

<table class="table room-table" data-price-p-person="400" data-ss="200">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">
            <label class="form-check-label selected-label" for="room-selected">Select</label>                                                   
        </th>
    </tr>

  </thead>
  <tbody>

 <tr>                                           
    <td class="persons"> 
        <select class="browser-default custom-select num-person select-update" name="number-persons-selection" required>
          <option value="0" selected>Select Number of Persons</option>
          <option value="1">1 person R600</option>
          <option value="2">2 persons R800</option>
          <option value="3">3 persons R1200</option>
          <option value="4">2 adults and one child under 5 years</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="dinner">
        <select class="browser-default custom-select num-dinner select-update" name="dinner-selection">
          <option value="0" selected>Select Dinner Course</option>
          <option class="option-two-course-dinn" value="120">Two Course Dinner R120</option>
          <option class="option-three-course-dinn" value="200">Three Course Dinner R200</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="view-total">
    <td><label for="room-total" class="tot">Total: R <input type="text" name="room-total" class="total" size="6" value="0" readonly="readonly" /></label></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<h1>Game of Thrones Room</h1>

<table class="table room-table" data-price-p-person="400" data-ss="200">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">
            <label class="form-check-label selected-label" for="room-selected">Select</label>                                                   
        </th>
    </tr>

  </thead>
  <tbody>

 <tr>                                           
    <td class="persons"> 
        <select class="browser-default custom-select num-person select-update" name="number-persons-selection" required>
          <option value="0" selected>Select Number of Persons</option>
          <option value="1">1 person R600</option>
          <option value="2">2 persons R800</option>
          <option value="3">3 persons R1200</option>
          <option value="4">2 adults and one child under 5 years R800</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="dinner">
        <select class="browser-default custom-select num-dinner select-update" name="dinner-selection">
          <option value="0" selected>Select Dinner Course</option>
          <option class="option-two-course-dinn" value="120">Two Course Dinner R120</option>
          <option class="option-three-course-dinn" value="200">Three Course Dinner R200</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="breakfast">
        <select class="browser-default custom-select num-bf select-update" name="bf-selection">
     <option value="0" selected>Select Breakfast</option>
       <option class="option-basic-bf" value="70">Basic R70</option>
       <option class="option-full-bf" value="120">Full R120</option>
    </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="view-total">
    <td><label for="room-total" class="tot">Total: R <input type="text" name="room-total" class="total" size="6" value="0" readonly="readonly" /></label></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<div class="grand-total-cont"><label for="grand-total" class="tot">Grand Total (inclusive with number of days): R <input type="text" class="grandtotal" size="6" value="0" readonly="readonly" name="grand-total" /></label></div>


<button name="submit-request" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />

</form>
```

Comment: I assume that jQuery code is inside an `onchange` handler? Please create a [mcve] (using the `<>` button in the question editor)

Comment: You need to save the original text somewhere, and then restore it. There's nothing built-in that will remember it.

Comment: All your selects are disabled?

Comment: @ChrisG yes it is `$('body').on('change', '.select-update', function(e){...` sorry I should have mentioned it

Comment: The main problem is that the handler fires on the select element, so `$(this).find('.num-person')` won't find anything, because `this` is the `<select>` itself.

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt, my apologies, the selects are in a form, I forgot to remove the disabled text, I have edited my post

Comment: @ChrisG, my HTML is in a table in a form, I also have `$('.room-table').each(function(){` coded before the `$(this).find('.num-person')`. That works fine, I just want to know how to set values back to default once I change back to a certain value.

Comment: `when I select option 4 on the first select dropdown then it changes the text of the other select dropdowns` --I dont see this happening?

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt, yes it does that. But when I decide: no I don't want option 4 anymore, but I now want option 1, I go and select option 1, I want the text of dinner and breakfast select options to change back to the default that is currently in the HTML

Comment: How do you decide which is the default value?

Comment: Look, if you start with `$('.room-table')` then `this` refers to the table, so it'll work. But if you use `$('body').on('change', '.select-update'` then `this` refers to the select, so `$(this).find('.num-person')` won't work. It's as simple as that.

Comment: The current text in the options in HTML of the select - the dinner and the breakfast select dropdowns. It changes when I select option 4 of the first select dropdown. But how do I restore the text that is currently in the HTML once I have gone back to option 1?

Comment: @ChrisG I start with `$('body').on('change', '.select-update'` and then `$('.room-table').each(function(){`, all my code works, I just want some direction on if I can go back to the text in the option if I change back to option 1

Comment: `all my code works` if it does because you fixed it, then please put your current code in the question. Right now, `num_persons` will be `NaN`. My solution is this: have all options, but hide those that don't apply: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/cktsdx7p/

Comment: @ChrisG I have added my code to show all (still a simplified way, but hopefully clearer). When I select option 4 the text changes. This is correct, it is what I want. But lets say I change my mind and decide to select option 1, I want the text to go back to the text coded in the HTML.

Comment: My question would be "why"? Why not move the text down to the JS code and set it like with option 4? It won't be visible before option 1 is selected anyway, so you might as well set it when that happens.

Comment: what is `breakfast` variable, it is undefined there

Comment: @ShridharSharma Fixed it, sorry I missed a few lines, I am trying to just use the code that is needed to show, my code is very long, so I am splitting it

Comment: @ChrisG, I am not sure what you mean... please take note that I am not very efficient yet in Jquery and I am open to improving my code, if you have suggestions. But I don't know what you are asking, because I can select option 4 first but then change my mind and want option 1 rather, so then the text must change back to what it was before I selected option 4. I have seen these things on websites before, I am not sure what the correct terms are for them

Comment: My code is fixed to run as a snippet, so that there can be clarity @ChrisG

Comment: I understand what your goal is, you don't need to tell me again and again. Anyway. Your current code is setting the 2nd select's options values after the user picks option 4. When they change their mind and pick option 1 now, you need to change them back. Since the original text is lost now, you have to store the text elsewhere anyway, regardless of whether you follow my specific advice. --- So again, my suggestion is to take the mechanism you use in `if (num_persons == 4)` and simply reuse it for `if (num_persons == 1)`. Like I said, the dinner options aren't visible earlier anyway.

Comment: @ChrisG thanks, I understand. The only thing that worries me is that I am going to have a lot more options than that - I don't want to set it for each value - e.g 2 and 3 persons, and there will be 2 adults and child above 5 options too. I feel it will be a lot of code being repeated. Your fiddle does not work with what I want. Any suggestion on how to prevent the repitition? And when I select option 4 then the text changes but the price values remain 0 until I select them, How should I approach this?

Comment: The best way to avoid repetition is to strictly separate data from presentation. Give me a few minutes and I'll create example code.

Comment: Alright, here's one way: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/cgfmxdpj/

Comment: @ChrisG, thanks I will try it out and upvote your comment :)